# update data in table per groups

Tags: oracle, sql-update

I want to write an simple update that will partly be used to harmonize the data of people in subgroups;

My table is:

```
CREATE TABLE table(
    id INT,
    PersonGroupId INT,
    PersonId INT,
    Value INT
);

INSERT INTO table(id, PersonGroupId, PersonId, Value)
VALUES
    (1, 100, 123, 1),
    (2, 100, 2, NULL),
    (3, 100, 3, 1),
    (4, 101, 2, 1),
    (5, 101, 3, NULL),
    (6, 102, 2, NULL),
    (7, 102, 3, NULL),
    (8, 103, 2, 1),
    (9, 103, 3, 1);
```

[Here is an example of what I want to achieve]

[image]

I have data:
firstPersonId = 2
secondPersonId = 3

I want to write an update like this:
Inside each subgroup(PersonGroupId) where personId=2 and personId=3 exist, change the value so that personId =2 and personId =3 have the same value, as follows:

| value of firstPerson | value of secondPerson | result (same for both people) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | null | 1 |
| null | 1 | 1 |
| 1 | 1 | 1 |
| null | null | null |

I tried writing updates, but I don't know how to make the command work separately for each PersonGroupId (that meets the conditions). Please help me how to write this

Comment: Please update your question to include the DDL for your tables and any SQL update commands you've tried so far. Do not post screenshots. We can't do much if you don't provide us enough information to reproduce your scenario accurately.

Answer (score 1):

here is one way :

```
update table1
set value = ( 
   select max(Value)
   from table1 t2
   group by persongroupid 
   having table1.persongroupid = t2.persongroupid
)
```

Comment: The OP only wants to update values based when `personid` is `2` or `3`; this will consider other values of `personid`. It will also update all the rows of the table; even those rows that do not need to be modified.

Comment: @MT0 then what's the point of the question, OP just can write one simple update and set the value for two rows manually!!!

Comment: If you have 1 billion rows in the table and the OP wants to update 500,000 of them then they don't want to update them manually and they don't want to update 1 billion rows; they only want to update the 500,000 rows that need updating. Your query may get the correct answer (it actually doesn't as you consider `person_id` values other than `2` or `3`) but it is going to update **EVERY** row in the table which, for a large data set, is incredibly inefficient. It is much more efficient to work out which rows need updating and only update those rows.

Answer (score 0):

`merge` is another option:

Before:

```
SQL> select * from test order by id;

        ID PERSONGROUPID   PERSONID      VALUE
---------- ------------- ---------- ----------
         1           100        123          1
         2           100          2
         3           100          3          1
         4           101          2          1
         5           101          3
         6           102          2
         7           102          3
         8           103          2          1
         9           103          3          1

9 rows selected.
```

Merge:

```
SQL> merge into test a
  2    using (select b.persongroupid,
  3                  max(b.value) max_value
  4           from test b
  5           where personid in (2, 3)
  6           group by b.persongroupid
  7           having count(distinct personid) >= 2
  8          ) x
  9    on (a.persongroupid = x.persongroupid)
 10  when matched then update set
 11    a.value = x.max_value;

9 rows merged.
```

After:

```
SQL> select * from test order by id;

        ID PERSONGROUPID   PERSONID      VALUE
---------- ------------- ---------- ----------
         1           100        123          1
         2           100          2          1
         3           100          3          1
         4           101          2          1
         5           101          3          1
         6           102          2
         7           102          3
         8           103          2          1
         9           103          3          1

9 rows selected.

SQL>
```

Comment: The OP only wants to update values based when `personid` is `2` or `3`; this will consider other values of `personid`. It will also update all the rows of the table; even those rows that do not need to be modified.

Comment: Right; missed that point, thank you. Fixed now.

Answer (score 0):

You use the `MAX` analytic function to find the maximum for each `persongroupid` considering only the values when `personid IN (2,3)` and then you can `MERGE` correlating on the `ROWID` pseudo-column (which is effectively a direct pointer to the row):

```sql
MERGE INTO table_name dst
USING (
  SELECT MAX(value) OVER (PARTITION BY persongroupid) AS max_value
  FROM   table_name
  WHERE  personid IN (2,3)
) src
ON (src.ROWID = dst.ROWID AND src.max_value IS NOT NULL)
WHEN MATCHED THEN
  UPDATE
  SET   value = max_value
  WHERE value IS NULL OR value != max_value;
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name(id, PersonGroupId, PersonId, Value) AS
SELECT 1, 100, 123, 1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 100, 2, NULL FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 3, 100, 3, 1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 4, 101, 2, 1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 5, 101, 3, NULL FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 6, 102, 2, NULL FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 7, 102, 3, NULL FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 8, 103, 2, 1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 9, 103, 3, 1 FROM DUAL;
```

Updates only the two rows that need changing and then the table contains:

| ID | PERSONGROUPID | PERSONID | VALUE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 100 | 123 | 1 |
| 2 | 100 | 2 | 1 |
| 3 | 100 | 3 | 1 |
| 4 | 101 | 2 | 1 |
| 5 | 101 | 3 | 1 |
| 6 | 102 | 2 | *null* |
| 7 | 102 | 3 | *null* |
| 8 | 103 | 2 | 1 |
| 9 | 103 | 3 | 1 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/HYxdqzGK)